# Create instance template from snapshot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

I've created a new GCE instance and took a snapshot of it's persistnet boot disk.
Now I would like to create a template based on this snapshot, to allow horizontal scaling, but I don't see the snapshot during the image selection when creating a new instance.

How can I create a new instance from an existing snapshot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapshots are just an instant representation of a persistent disk **only**. It does not save the google configurations of the instance using it. Nothing forbid you to take a snapshot of an unattached disk for example. Moreover, a snapshot is not bootable, it means that you have to create an **image** from it.

In order to create an instance group, you have to create an image from you snapshot you've taken **and** you have to create an instance template base on that newly created image.

Comment: Thank you. I will try . Obviously any network-related configuration stored in my snapshotted boot disk would be changed accordingly, in the new instance, right? There is no risk of conflicting IP and so on...

Comment: Absolutely ! There are no static network configuration on instances.

Comment: I can't find how to create an instance template to be based on a custom image as the boot disk. I can only attach it as a secondary disk, but even that has to be unattached, meaning that cannot use it in an instance group. How can do that?

Comment: You can create an instance directly from snapshot now. @GandalfCorvotempesta